# Total Days between two dates

Tags: php, datediff

i am beginner at php. I want to calculate exact total number of days between two dates using php, mysql and want to show it in html form. I tried datediff but it doesn't works  as it gives , diffrence not total number of days.

Date fm - 10-10-22;
Date to - 20-10-22;
Total Days - 11

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.

Answer (score 1):

add + 1  to date_diff the output will 11 be like :

```
<?php
$d1=date_create("2022-10-10");
$d2=date_create("2022-10-20");
$diff=date_diff($d1,$d2);
echo $result = 1 + $diff->format("%R%a days");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

php has inbuilt `DateTime` functions to get the difference. Below outputs 10 day difference.

```php
$date = new DateTime('2022-10-20');
$next_date = new DateTime('2022-10-30');
echo $date->diff($next_date)->days;
```